# Command Substitution in Bash for tty

Tags: bash, tty, command-substitution

Command:

```
echo "a" | tee `tty`
```

Output:

```
a
```

Command:

```
echo "a" | tee /dev/pts/0
```

Output:

```
a
a
```

File connected with current terminal is `/dev/pts/0`.
Shouldn't both commands produce same output? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tee` duplicates stdin to all file descriptors given on the command line *and* to stdout, so if one of the files it the current terminal (you can also use `-`) then input will be written twice on stdout.

In the first case, stdin is not connected to a tty (but to the output of the `echo` command), so `tty` gives `not a tty`.  So the command becomes `echo "a" | tee not a tty`, and you will have three files (called "not" "a" and "tty") each containing "a", as well as "a" written to stdout.